# Firefox Password Field is not empty

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I'm new here on stack**overflow**.

I'm writing a Form to add a Album to a gallery, but now I discovered a problem in Firefox which I've never had. The password field is already set. I never filled out the form.

Does somebody knows, why Firefox fills text in?

Comment: If you have formfill option enabled and set to autofill, its grabbing it from saved form data and prefilling it based on the name of the textbox. Check there.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a saved password, you will be able to find it in the security and password settings (see [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/security-and-passwords-settings) for more information).  If you've saved a password on a different portion of the site (say you have a form on www.site.com/login.html and www.site.com/admin.html for example), it could be pulling it from there.